# indexディレクティブを使うとリダイレクトが発生してしまう

Tags: nginx

NginxでURLパスを静的ファイルにマッピングする設定を行っています。

`http://www.test.com/foo/` とアクセスしたら、実際は、 
`http://www.test.com/foo.php` が実行されるイメージです。

設定としては、`locaion{index..}` という方式で行っています。 
上記の例だと以下のような設定をしてます。

```
location /foo {
   index foo.php
}
```

### 意図しない動作

仕様ではindexディレクティブは、指定されたファイルへ内部リダイレクションされるとあります。しかし、実際は外部リダイレクション(301 Moved Permanently)され、ブラウザに戻ってきてから、再度、サーバに要求を飛ばす動作になってしまっています。

そのため、POSTで要求を投げた場合、indexディレクティブにより、外部リダイレクションされ、それを受けたブラウザは、GETでリダイレクト(ほとんどのブラウザの仕様)するため、サーバはGETでしか認識できないのと、その際、POSTのパラメータが欠落してしまいます。

### やりたいこと

`http://www.test.com/foo/` にアクセスし、 `http://www.test.com/foo.php` と実行させたい。 
実現できれば、`location{index}` 形式でなくてもよい。 
とにかくブラウザに301(302, 303, 307)でリダイレクトされるのをやめたい。

Comment: 設定ファイルの内容を省略せずに載せることはできますか？いまの3行だけだとトラブルシューティングは難しそうです。また、ログにエラーなどが出力されていませんでしたか？ログに問題のヒントあるかもしれません。追加の情報があれば質問を編集して、追記してください。質問の編集はSOでは推奨されてます。

Answer (score 1):

rewrite を使うといいと思います。

```
location /foo {
    rewrite /foo /foo.php;
}
```